# Fetch Metadata of a model using model derivative api (Forge)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I was trying some hands on with forge services, I want to fetch few object's properties inside of a revit model uploaded on bim360/ACC, for which I am calling two API's 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' for translating the job to svf and then calling API "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/" + urn + "/metadata/" (with urn of the translated job) (failed when passed urn of revit file directly)

Can we not directly get the metadata/properties without converting the file to svf? Since translating to svf is taking a lot of time for large files, my motive is to decrease the time to fetch the properties, can you share any solutions if you think of any please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct in assuming that you need to translate to SVF in order to access any BIM element properties at all. It's either that, or open it in desktop Revit and access the data there. Also discussed in the Revit API discussion forum thread on [fetching metadata of a model using Forge model derivative API](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/fetch-metadata-of-a-model-using-model-derivative-api-forge/m-p/11246985).

Comment: AFAIK, files uploaded to BIM360 / ACC are automatically translated into SVF / SVF2 ?

Comment: Yes, indeed, so the SVF is already present in the system. Now all you need to do is gain access, e.g., by loading it into the Forge viewer. There, you can use JavaScript to read the data.

Comment: Before calling properties API, will need to wait for the svf2 translation job completed.

Comment: @JeremyTammik I want to use the Metadata of a revit file uploaded on acc/bim360 in my forge app. How can I get it without translating the file to svf. Since translation is taking a lot of time. As you said, files uploaded are already translated to svf. How can I get metadata for the file which is already translated? Please help. 

I also tried another solution of using the nwd file. But I also had issues in it. Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72861685/fetch-metadata-of-a-nwd-file-using-forge

Comment: Eason has provided the answer. It is correct and complete. You can trust him.